# Is there a quick python way to get a range response, if i type 1 it gives "1-10" and so on

Tags: python, numbers, range

I am getting into a problem statement for a script where i need to change int to a string with a range like 1-10 , 11-20 and so on. Using simple if else in python is not a good option for bugger numbers. Does someone know of any function to help out with this in python?

for example:

i am reading the numbers from a pandas dataframe each cell has different numbers:
so if i put the number in like the function-

convertnumtorange(1) it should give "1-10"
convertnumtorange(27) it should give "21-30"

Comment: Could you edit the question with some examples? Input and expected output

Comment: "change int to a string"—According to what precise rules?

Comment: @RiccardoBucco i have added an example of how the expected output i am looking for.

Comment: should the difference between the starting and end range be only 10

Comment: Can be a variable, so if the range length needed is of 5 numbers the starting and end range can will be 5. the above example gives 10.

Comment: @martineau i am not asking for show me how to. I wanted to know if there is a lib or a function that can help. as i am not able to find any

Comment: "Shopping" for a library is also off topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
def convertnumtorange(n):
    b = (n - 1) // 10 * 10 + 10
    a = b - 9
    return f'{a}-{b}'
```

Examples:

```
>>> convertnumtorange(1)
'1-10'
>>> convertnumtorange(27)
'21-30'
```

Let's say you have a data frame with numbers:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'n': [1, 27]})
>>> df
    n
0   1
1  27
>>> df['range'] = df['n'].apply(convertnumtorange)
>>> df
    n  range
0   1   1-10
1  27  21-30
```

Comment: Thanks for it. I will try to make it to work with different ranges. But this works good.